# Hiding the status bar

Tags: iphone

We have hidden the status bar in our application. But when there is an error in playing the video, I get "This movie could not be played" pop up. When this pop up is getting displayed, status bar becomes visible and it stays visible always till we shut down the application.

How do we fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setStatusBarHidden:true animated:false ];
```